# PHP echo without a loop. SQL Query

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Here is the subject matter: [Link](http://www.ecmayhem.com/roster-blk.php), Click a players name to see.

I want to have the players name as a header so that the players name isn't  repeated over and over again for each resulting row in the Roster table. I know how to loop through results for rows, but I only want the name once at the top and don't know how to do that. This is how I print the table code wise

```
<?php

$pid = $_POST['PID'];
$query = "SELECT Rosters.PID, Rosters.Goals, Rosters.Assists, Rosters.PIM, Rosters.Num, Rosters.TID, Players.pid, Players.firstname, Players.lastname,
            (Rosters.Goals + Rosters.Assists) AS Points
             FROM Rosters
             INNER JOIN Players
             ON Rosters.PID = Players.pid
             WHERE Rosters.PID = $pid
             ORDER BY Points DESC, Goals DESC";
$result = $conn->query($query);

$query2 = "SELECT Rosters.PID, SUM( Rosters.Goals ) Goals, SUM( Rosters.Assists ) Assists, SUM( Rosters.PIM ) PIM, Rosters.Num, Rosters.TID, Players.pid, Players.firstname, Players.lastname, 
              SUM((Rosters.Goals + Rosters.Assists)) AS Points
              FROM Rosters
              INNER JOIN Players ON Rosters.PID = Players.pid
              WHERE Rosters.PID =$pid
              ORDER BY Points DESC , Goals DESC";
$result2 = $conn->query($query2);
echo

if (!empty($_POST["PID"])) {
    echo "<table class='stat-table-wide table sortable' align='center'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th class='hover'>Season</th>";
    echo "<th class='hover'>Num</th>";
    echo "<th class='hover'>Player</th>";
    echo "<th class='hover'>G</th>";
    echo "<th class='hover'>A</th>";
    echo "<th class='hover'>Pts</th>";
    echo "<th class='hover'>PIM</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $i = 13;
    $j = 14;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $i++;
        $j++;
        $goals = $row["Goals"];
        $assists = $row["Assists"];
        $points = $goals + $assists;
        echo "<tr><td>20" . $i . "-20" . $j . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["Num"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["firstname"] . " " . $row["lastname"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["Goals"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["Assists"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["Points"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["PIM"] . "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<span class='style35'>Total</span><br />";
    echo "<table class='stat-table-wide table sortable' align='center'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th class='hover'>Player</th>";
    echo "<th class='hover'>G</th>";
    echo "<th class='hover'>A</th>";
    echo "<th class='hover'>Pts</th>";
    echo "<th class='hover'>PIM</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
        $goals = $row["Goals"];
        $assists = $row["Assists"];
        $points = $goals + $assists;
        echo "<td>" . $row["firstname"] . " " . $row["lastname"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["Goals"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["Assists"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["Points"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["PIM"] . "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

I just want Players.firstname and Players.lastname printed once before any of the tables are generated.

Comment: hmm the preview shows my code formatted.....Edit: fixed.

Comment: replace  SELECT Rosters.PID With DISTINCT(Rosters.PID)

Comment: Works the same as in the loop, just do one `$rows =$result->fetch_assoc();` in front of the loop.

Comment: What is wrong with my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!empty($_POST["PID"])) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo "<span class='style35'>" . $row["firstname"] . " " . $row["lastname"] . "</span><br />";
    $result->data_seek(0);
    echo "<table class='stat-table-wide table sortable' align='center'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th class='hover'>Season</th>";
    echo "<th class='hover'>Num</th>";
    echo "<th class='hover'>G</th>";
    echo "<th class='hover'>A</th>";
    echo "<th class='hover'>Pts</th>";
    echo "<th class='hover'>PIM</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $i = 13;
    $j = 14;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $i++;
        $j++;
        $goals = $row["Goals"];
        $assists = $row["Assists"];
        $points = $goals + $assists;
        echo "<tr><td>20" . $i . "-20" . $j . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["Num"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["Goals"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["Assists"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["Points"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["PIM"] . "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<span class='style35'>Total</span><br />";
    echo "<table class='stat-table-wide table sortable' align='center'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th class='hover'>Player</th>";
    echo "<th class='hover'>G</th>";
    echo "<th class='hover'>A</th>";
    echo "<th class='hover'>Pts</th>";
    echo "<th class='hover'>PIM</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
        $goals = $row["Goals"];
        $assists = $row["Assists"];
        $points = $goals + $assists;
        echo "<td>" . $row["firstname"] . " " . $row["lastname"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["Goals"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["Assists"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["Points"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["PIM"] . "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

I don't know if you wanted the name of the player in the totals, so I left it there, but you can delete it if you want. I also applied to the player name the same style as the total.

Comment: Thank you. "$result->data_seek(0);" seems to be what I need to learn about.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the first row of the result before your loop, then just reset the cursor, and completely ignore the players name inside your loop.

```
$first = $result->fetch_assoc();

// print out first name
echo($first['name'] . " " . $first['surname']);

// reset cursor
$result->data_seek(0);

// do your loops and stuff.
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Pavlin, someone else had a similar solution. I gave you a 1+ because you had the same solution with `$result->data_seek(0);`

Answer (score 1):

You can do  like this.If you do not want to change the sql query.

```
$ctr = 0;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$ctr++;
if($ctr == 1) {
echo "</table>";
echo "<span class='style35'>Total</span><br />";
echo "<table class='stat-table-wide table sortable' align='center'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th class='hover'>Player</th>";
echo "<th class='hover'>G</th>";
echo "<th class='hover'>A</th>";
echo "<th class='hover'>Pts</th>";
echo "<th class='hover'>PIM</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["firstname"] . " " . $row["lastname"] . "</td> </tr>";
}
    $i++;
    $j++;
    $goals = $row["Goals"];
    $assists = $row["Assists"];
    $points = $goals + $assists;
    echo "<tr><td>20" . $i . "-20" . $j . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["Num"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["firstname"] . " " . $row["lastname"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["Goals"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["Assists"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["Points"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["PIM"] . "</td></tr>";
}
```